# Getting internal server error on Flask App hosted on Azure

Tags: python, azure, flask, azure-web-app-service

I've hosted a flask app on Azure, but there seems to be some problem with linking the WSGIHandler. It is a very simple bug. I can't seem to identify it.
The following is the error I'm getting in my Logs

```
Error occurred while reading WSGI handler:

Traceback (most recent call last):


File "D:\Python27\Scripts\wfastcgi.py", line 711, in main
    env, handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path)
  File "D:\Python27\Scripts\wfastcgi.py", line 568, in read_wsgi_handler
    return env, get_wsgi_handler(handler_name)
  File "D:\Python27\Scripts\wfastcgi.py", line 551, in get_wsgi_handler
    raise ValueError('"%s" could not be imported' % handler_name)
ValueError: "App" could not be imported


StdOut: 

StdErr: 
ErrorCode   Access is denied.
 (0x5)
```

Here is my folder structure

```
myapplication
  -- App
      -- __init__.py
```

The contents of `__init__.py` is

```
from flask import Flask
# initialize the flask app
app = Flask(__name__)

print "init"
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "hello world";

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I've configured the following App Settings in Azure Web App

PYTHONPATH = D:\home\site\wwwroot

WSGI_HANDLER = App.app

Comment: What does your `web.config` look like? One thing you can do is create a simple Flask app from here https://tryappservice.azure.com/?language=python&name=Flask then click on the Visual Studio Online link and see what the difference between your app and the one that works is

Comment: @ahmelsayed I do not have a web.config file. I'll check on that. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: np, from what I can see there you might need a `web.config` that includes a handler mapping for python's fcgi and a url rewrite rule. If you're able to figure out what was wrong make sure to post an answer to your own question to help others who may hit the same issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, your deployment is incompleteness, as Azure uses IIS to host python web sites on Web Apps Services, which needs a web.config to configure hander mapping and URL rewrite rules and some other settings.

To create and deploy a flask project on Azure Web Apps , we can generally follow the steps below:

1, On [Azure manage portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/), click **NEW** => **COMPUTE** => **WEB APP** =>**FROM GALLERY** at the bottom navigation, on the **ADD WEB APP** dialog, select Flask, name the site on the next dialog page. Now we have created a flask web site project.
 [image]
We can type the endpoint on the browser to check the website, `http://<your_site_name>.azurewebsite.net`

2,On the web apps list, click the name we created above to get into the configuration page, click **DASHBOARD**, at the **quick glance** column, click **Set up deployment from source control** ,select Local Git repository. Now there is an additional tab named **DEPLOYMENT** beside the **DASHBOARD** tab. And in the **DEPLOYMENT** page there are steps of how to deploy your site by git. We can clone the project to local by the GIT URL provided on this page.
[image]

We can get more on [this official article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-create-deploy-flask-app/)